# Offline transaction signing with web3j?

Tags: transactions, web3j, java

I'd like to generate and sign a transaction offline and then send that transaction with a different account.  I've found a few web3js sources and I've read the web3 documentation, but I haven't found any clear solutions for doing this in Java with web3j.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: what do you mean by "different account"? If you sign the transaction offline by one account, that's the account that will send the transaction, not another account

Comment: I want to create a signed raw transaction that can be broadcast by a third-party (someone other than the user who created the transaction).  I misspoke when I said "different account."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this should work

```
// Create the Transaction
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(<nonce>, <gasPrice>, 
       <gasLimit>, <to>, <value>);  

// Sign the Transaction
byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, <your-Credentials>);

String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
```

and then give the hexValue to the third-party to broadcast it to the network

**Update**: now you need the chain ID to the method singMessage, like this:

```
long chainId = <the id of the used chain>
byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, chainId , <you Credentials>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to dig around [`SignedRawTransaction`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/SignedRawTransaction.java) and [`TransactionEncoder`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/TransactionEncoder.java) classes.

Answer (score 1):

answer from Majd TL is correct.
Here is whole simple implementation with Web3j to create a raw transaction. I believe it can be handy for someone.

```
final Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("<node>"));

final Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("*******");
final String to = "0x*****";
final String amount = "0.1";
final long ropstenChainId = 3;

EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(credentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).send();
BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();

BigInteger gasPrice = web3j.ethGasPrice().send().getGasPrice();
BigInteger gasLimit = DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT;

RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, Convert.toWei(amount, Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger());

byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, ropstenChainId, credentials);

String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
System.out.println(hexValue);
```

And the correct chainId you can find here - https://chainlist.org/

Comment: Full example helpful to newbies :-)